How do I get my inline editing Vue component to update the value after editing?
I'm working on a simple inline editing component for a project, and have it mostly working, except that once the edit happens, the bound variable doesn't update the way I'd like it.
The basic approach is that I have a table cell that just has the variable text, and then on double-click I swap in an input field populated with the text value.
Why is the computedCellValue not getting the updated value of the input when it gets edited?
<script setup>
    import { defineProps, ref, computed, nextTick } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps([
        "cellValue",
        "prefix",
        "postfix"
    ]);

    const isEditing = ref(false);
    const inputField = ref(null);
    const computedCellValue = computed(() => props.cellValue);

    function toggleEditOn() {
        isEditing.value = true;

        nextTick(function () {
            inputField.value.focus();
            inputField.value.select();
        });
    }

    function toggleEditOff() {
        isEditing.value = false;
    }
</script>

<template>
    <td class="w-64 mx-1" @dblclick="toggleEditOn()" v-show="isEditing == false">
        {{ props.prefix }}{{ computedCellValue }}{{ props.postfix }}
    </td>
    <td class="w-64 mx-1" v-show="isEditing == true">
        {{ props.prefix }}<input class="w-64 bg-slate-400 p-1 text-white" ref="inputField" type="text" :value="computedCellValue"  @blur="toggleEditOff()" @focus="focused" @keyup.enter="toggleEditOff()">{{ props.postfix }}
    </td>
</template>


computedCellValue always returns the value of props.cellValue, that's it's job as a computed property.  There is no attempt to update the prop value, therefore there is nothing to recompute and the computed value stays the same.
If you want there to be two-way binding between the input and the prop, it's a job for v-model. Props should be treated as read-only however, so instead of a prop you should also use defineModel (which is syntactic sugar that still uses props under the hood but automatically handles emitting new values for the parent component to update)
So instead of sending cellValue down as a prop, it should be set as the v-model.
Parent.vue
<template>
  <Child v-model="cellValue" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const cellValue = ref('')
</script>

cellValue in the child should then be defined with defineModel() and binded to the input with v-model
Child.vue (simplified)
<template>
  <input 
    v-model="cellValue"
    type="text" 
  >
</template>

<script setup>
const cellValue = defineModel()
</script>

Vue Playground example
